# Web3 - How do I view my own address?

Tags: web3js

How do I get my own address into a variable when I use HDWallet as provider for Web3?

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
Web3 = require("web3");
let provider = new HDWalletProvider('claim .. ... ... .. .. blah','https://sandbox.truffleteams.com/blah/blah')

web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

---

I have tried:

```
web3.eth.accounts[0] is empty
web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress is empty
web3.eth.getAccounts(accounts => console.log(accounts[0])) is empty
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: does the problem persist if you use `http` instead of `https` for the URL in the third line?

Comment: I changed my code to do this, and it works:
```function getMyAddress(callback){ 
  web3.eth.getAccounts((error,data)=>{
    callback(data[0])
  })
}
```